# Was writing code for a slot machine in java and and want to split into 3 files but it doesnt work

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, slot

Dont know what isnt working

```
//slot machine class
package slotMachine;

//import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


# public class SlotGame {

    private int winCreadits=0;
    private boolean winState;
    static int slotMidPosition= 0;
    Random rand = new Random(); 


    //wheel contains: "melon", "bell", "7", "lemon", "bar" (5 total icons)
    static String slotBand[] = {"melon", " bell", "    7", "lemon", "  bar"};


        // slotOut is used to store the output values for the slot machine
    static String slotOut[] = new String[]
            {
                    "melon","melon","melon" 
            };
    public SlotGame()
     {
     init();    



     }

     public void checkWin()
     {
    checkConections();
    if(winState)
    {
        if (slotOut[1]=="melon")
        {
            winCreadits=1;
        }
        else if (slotOut[1]=="lemon")
        {
            winCreadits=1;
        }
        else if (slotOut[1]=="bell")
        {
            winCreadits=2;
        }
        else if (slotOut[1]=="bar")
        {
            winCreadits=3;
        }
        else if (slotOut[1]=="7")
        {
            winCreadits=5;
        }
        else 
        {
            winCreadits=0;
        }
    }


     }

     public int getWinAmount()
     {
        return winCreadits;
     }

     public String[] returnWheel()
     {
        return slotOut;
     }

     private void init()
     {
        getSlot( );

     }

     public void getSlot()
     {
    winState=false;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        slotMidPosition = rand.nextInt(5);
        if (slotMidPosition==0)
        {
            slotOut[0]=slotBand[4];
        }
        else if(slotMidPosition>=0)
        {
            slotOut[0]=slotBand[slotMidPosition-1];
        }

        slotOut[1]=slotBand[slotMidPosition];

        slotOut[2]=slotBand[(slotMidPosition+1)%5];
         }
    checkWin();
     }


     private void outputArray(String[] slotOut)
     {
         for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
        {


            System.out.print(slotOut[i]);
            System.out.print(" ");



        }
     }
  dont know wats going on at a point




         public void checkConections()
     {
    if(slotOut[0]==slotOut[1]&&slotOut[1]==slotOut[2])
        winState = true;
    else
        winState=false;
     }



     }
```

CONTROLLER CLASS

```
    package slotMachine;


    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
    import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
    import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import edu.cuny.csi.csc330.swing.TTTGameView;




    public class SlotController implements 
    ActionListener, 
    WindowListener{

private boolean ifWork=false;
private SlotView gameView;
private SlotGame gameModel;
private int winAmount;
private String wheel[];

public SlotController() {
    init();
}

public void setGameView(SlotView gameView) {
    this.gameView = gameView;
}

private void init()
{
    gameModel = new SlotGame();
}

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    Object source = ae.getSource();
    ifWork= (source == this.gameView.getSpinButton());
    System.out.println(ifWork);
    System.out.println("Slot actionPerformed: "  +                                              
    source.getClass().getSimpleName());
    // Spin button 
    if(source == this.gameView.getSpinButton() ) 
    {
        winAmount = gameView.getCreadit();
        System.out.println(gameView.getCreadit());
        gameModel.getSlot();
        wheel=gameModel.returnWheel();
        winAmount+= gameModel.getWinAmount();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wheel));
        gameView.setCredit(winAmount);
        gameView.spunWheelDec();
        gameView.importWheel(wheel);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gameView.wheelSet()));

    }



}



@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SlotView.present();

    }
}
```

//SlotView for gui

```
package slotMachine;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;

import edu.cuny.csi.csc330.swing.TTTController;
import edu.cuny.csi.csc330.swing.TTTGameView;







public class SlotView extends JFrame{

private static Integer DEFAULT_X = 200;
private static Integer DEFAULT_Y = 200;
private static Integer DEFAULT_W = 1000; 
private static Integer DEFAULT_H = 500;


private static String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Spinny Thing Game";


private String[] Wheel= new String[3];

private JButton spinButton;

private ImageIcon imageArr1;
private ImageIcon imageArr2;
private ImageIcon imageArr3;
private ImageIcon image;
private JLabel imageIcone;


private JPanel mainPanel;
private JLabel SlotPos_1;
private JLabel SlotPos_2;
private JLabel SlotPos_3;
private JPanel Slot_1;
private JPanel Slot_2;
private JPanel Slot_3;
private JPanel slotPanel; 
private JPanel CreditPanel;
private JPanel betPanel; 
private JPanel mainOutPut;

private JLabel  currentBet;
private JLabel  currentPoints;
private JLabel  pointsLabel;
private JLabel  betLabel;


private ActionListener actionListener;  
private WindowListener windowListener;



private int credit, bet=1;




public SlotView() {
    guiInit();
}

public SlotView(SlotController listener) {
    actionListener = listener;
    windowListener = listener;
    guiInit();
}

    public SlotView(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
    super(gc);
    guiInit();
}

public void setCredit(int cred)
{
    credit = cred;
}

public void spunWheelDec()
{
    credit-=bet;
    this.pointsLabel=createStatusLabel(String.format("%d", credit) );
}

public int getCreadit()
{
    return credit;
}
public JLabel getCurentPoints() {
    return this.currentPoints;
}

public JLabel getCurrentBet() {
    return currentBet;
}

public JButton getSpinButton(){
    return spinButton;
}

private void init()
{
    credit=50;
    this.setSize(DEFAULT_W, DEFAULT_H);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));

    this.setLocation(DEFAULT_X, DEFAULT_X);
    //this.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 500);
    this.setTitle(DEFAULT_TITLE);

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);



}

private void image()
{


      for(int i = 0; i<3;i++) {

        if (Wheel[i]=="melon")
            imageArr1 = new 
        ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Watermelon.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="bell")
            imageArr1= new 
             ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Bell.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="7")
            imageArr1= new 
               ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Seven.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="lemon")
            imageArr1= new 
           ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Cherry.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="bar")
            imageArr1= new 
               ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Bar.png");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<3;i++) {

        if (Wheel[i]=="melon")
            imageArr2 = new 
          ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Watermelon.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="bell")
            imageArr2= new 
                 ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Bell.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="7")
            imageArr2= new 
             ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Seven.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="lemon")
            imageArr2= new 
         ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Cherry.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="bar")
            imageArr2= new 
              ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Bar.png");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<3;i++) {

        if (Wheel[i]=="melon")
            imageArr3 = new 
          ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Watermelon.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="bell")
            imageArr3= new 
             ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Bell.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="7")
            imageArr3= new 
         ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Seven.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="lemon")
            imageArr3= new 
     ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Cherry.png");
        if (Wheel[i]=="bar")
            imageArr3= new                  
    ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bn\\Pictures\\images\\Bar.png");
    }





}

private JLabel createStatusLabel(String title)  {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(title);
    label.setName( title );
    label.setFont( new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18) );
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 35));
    label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    return label; 
}
public void importWheel(String[] W)
{
    Wheel=W;
}

public void setWheels()
{
    Slot_1.add(SlotPos_1);
    Slot_2.add(SlotPos_2);
    Slot_3.add(SlotPos_3);
}

public String[] wheelSet()
{
    return Wheel;
}


private void guiInit() {

    init();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    currentBet = createStatusLabel("Bet: ");
    currentPoints = createStatusLabel("Credit: ");



    SlotPos_1= new JLabel(imageArr1);   
    SlotPos_1.setBounds(0, 0, 181, 163);

    SlotPos_2= new JLabel(imageArr2);
    SlotPos_2.setBounds(0, 0, 181, 163);


    SlotPos_3=new JLabel(imageArr3);
    SlotPos_3.setBounds(0, 0, 181, 163);



    //set up a main panel for slot wheels
    slotPanel = new JPanel();
    slotPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 205));
    slotPanel.setBounds(40, 40, 914, 185);
    slotPanel.setLayout(null);

    //set up slot 1
    Slot_1 = new JPanel();
    Slot_1.add(SlotPos_1);
    Slot_1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Slot_1.setBounds(10, 11, 181, 163);
    slotPanel.add(Slot_1);
    Slot_1.setLayout(null);


    //set slot 2
    Slot_2 = new JPanel();
    Slot_2.add(SlotPos_2);
    Slot_2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Slot_2.setBounds(360, 11, 181, 163);
    slotPanel.add(Slot_2);
    Slot_2.setLayout(null);
    Slot_2.setVisible(true);

    //set slot 3
    Slot_3 = new JPanel();
    Slot_3.add(SlotPos_3);
    Slot_3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Slot_3.setBounds(723, 11, 181, 163);
    slotPanel.add(Slot_3);
    Slot_3.setLayout(null);
    Slot_3.setVisible(true);

    // set up for data output and buttons
    mainOutPut = new JPanel();
    mainOutPut.setBackground(new Color(112, 128, 144));
    mainOutPut.setBounds(40, 283, 914, 160);
    mainOutPut.setLayout(null);


    // outputs credit value
    CreditPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2), true);
    CreditPanel.setBackground(new Color(112, 128, 144));
    CreditPanel.setBounds(10, 65, 222, 57);
    CreditPanel.add(currentPoints);
    pointsLabel=createStatusLabel(String.format("%d", credit) );
    CreditPanel.add(pointsLabel);
    mainOutPut.add(CreditPanel);

    //output for bets
    betPanel = new JPanel();
    betPanel.setBackground(new Color(112, 128, 144));
    betPanel.setBounds(682, 65, 222, 65);
    betPanel.add(currentBet);
    betLabel = createStatusLabel(Integer.toString(bet));
    betPanel.add(betLabel);
    mainOutPut.add(betPanel);

    //creates button for spinning the wheel
    spinButton = new JButton("SPIN WHEEL");
    spinButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    spinButton.setBackground(new Color(34, 139, 34));
    spinButton.setBounds(381, 57, 139, 65);
    mainOutPut.add(spinButton);







    this.getContentPane().add(slotPanel);       
    this.getContentPane().add(mainOutPut);      

    //this.setVisible(true);
    addActionListeners();
    addOtherListeners();
}

private void addActionListeners() {
    if(this.actionListener == null)
            return; 

    this.spinButton.addActionListener(this.actionListener); 
}





private void addOtherListeners() {
    addWindowListener(windowListener);

}

public static void present() {

     // The recommended way of startin a Swing / GUI Thread 
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                SlotController listener = new SlotController(); 
                SlotView game = new SlotView(listener);
                listener.setGameView(game);

                game.setVisible(true);

            }
        }
      );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    present();
/*  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000,400));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    JPanel jpn = new JPanel();
    //frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jpn);

    JButton spin= new JButton("spin");
    spin.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
    jpn.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    jpn.add(spin);

    frame.setTitle("Test");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    */
}
```

}

it does not take the images that i am requesting of it anddisplaying them. 
also the credit does not get updated

Comment: Your title indicates one problem (trying to separate code into three files within a package) and the end of your post indicates another. Which one is it? If it's both, separate them out into two different questions. Also, please consult this [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. ..

Comment: 4) **Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.** 5) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 0):

because you do not create a folder within your project that is in the same package and then move them there and no longer uses such external routes I'll give you an example
let's say that they create a folder called images in the package where I have my project so the routes will only have to give it

```
ImageIcon("imagenes/imagen.png");
```

change

```
ImageIcon ("C: \\ Users \\ bn \\ Pictures \\ images \\ Watermelon.png");
```

by

```
 ImageIcon ("C: \ Users \ bn \ Pictures \\ images \ Watermelon.png");
```

Comment: This would make the code look for the file in a directory relative to the location that the code was executed from, which could result in the images not been loaded